# How to access values returned by the column names idxmin/idxmax?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

Let's say I have this dataframe

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,5], 'B':[3,4]})
   A  B
0  1  3
1  5  4
```

I can get the minimum value of each row with:

```
> df.min(1)
0    1
1    4
dtype: int64
```

Or its indexes with:

```
> df.idxmin(1)
0    A
1    B
dtype: object
```

Nevertheless, this implies **searching the minimum values twice**. Is there a way to use the `idxmin` results to access the respective columns and get the minimum value (without calling `min`)?

---

**Edit**:  I am looking for something that is faster than calling `min` again. In theory, this should be possible as columns are indexed.

Answer (score 1):

To get the values in a list, you could do the following:

```
> indicies = df.idxmin(1)
> [df.iloc[k][indicies[k]] for k in range(len(indicies))]
  [1, 4]
```

Comment: thanks @rammelmueller, I changed for `[df.iloc[k][v] for k, v in enumerate(idxmin)]`, but unfortunately this is slower than calling `min`. I tested with several subsets of my data and it just gets worse (between 10x to 100x sloweer) the more data I have (I do have just six columns, but I am expecting a lot of rows)

Comment: using python to loop through a dataframe will almost always be significantly slower than letting pandas loop through a dataframe.

Comment: yeah, sorry I didn't run any benchmarks on that.. but kevinsa5 is right, pandas is typically the most performant option.